# How to add the font David to AbiWord?

Tags: fonts, abiword

Ubuntu 16.04

I'd like to add the font David to AbiWord.
What should I do?

Help much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to own the David font and for that, you need to buy it. You can buy the fonts here https://www.fonts.com/font/masterfont/david

David font also comes pre-installed with Windows. https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1884

After you grab the fonts, copy them to `~/.local/share/fonts` directory. Abiword should be able to see the fonts then.